# Using several SSL certificates on same IP with IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've got several domains (different sites with different domains. not sub-domains) which need SSL.

I couldn't find a way to make it work - so that each domain will have its SSL certificate, but use the same port and IP as the other domains.

Can this be accomplished?

If not, should I buy a different IP for each domain that needs a SSL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind only one SSL certificate per IP:port pair. If you need to run 2 HTTPS on the same IP -- bind them to different ports and then refer to such site providing port in URL (e.g. `https://beta.example.com:444/`). Otherwise you need another IP.

The reason is -- HTTP protocol kicks in only **after** secure channel has been established, which means only 1 SSL certificate can be used.

If you would have only one domain and wildcart certificate (`*.domain.com`), then you could try this article: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html , but your situation is different.

Comment: Server Name Indication, and IIS' lack of support for it, is worth a mention.