# Securing Two Sub domains on IIS7.5 with SSL on port 443

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, https

I have two sub domains pointing at the same IP address i.e.

**sub1.example.com**

**sub2.example.com**

Each sub domain maps to a site (let's say sub1 and sub2, respectively) in IIS 7.5 on Windows server 2008 R2. Both sites are non-production sites (a dev and a release candidate).

What I'd like to do is enable HTTPS on both sites via SSL certificate(s) and have access to both sites on port 443. I have downloaded [SelfSSL7](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/04/16/setting-up-ssl-made-easy.aspx) in order to generate certificate(s) to use, but I am having trouble with understanding how all the pieces go together.

As I understand it, I need to enable a HTTPS binding for each site via

```
Right Click -> Edit Bindings... -> Add Https binding
```

Going this route does not allow one to edit the `Host Name`, which in the case of `sub1.example.com` I believe I need to set to `sub1.example.com`.

I can generate a certificate with SelfSSL7 on the command line using

```
SelfSSL7 /N cn=sub1.example.com /K 2048 /V 3650 /I /S "sub1" /P443 /A * /T
```

This adds the certificate under the `Server Certificates` in IIS 7.5 and also adds it as the certificate to use for site `sub1`. The Host name under the HTTPS binding for `sub1` is still blank however.

Now, If I go and attempt to generate another certificate for `sub2` using the above command (and substituting the `cn` name and site name appropriately), a message comes up

```
SSL Binding for *:443: already exists. Use /Q to overwrite
```

If I understand correctly, the first certificate that I have generated is being used for any host headers that come through on port 443. The end result being that a request to either `https://sub1.example.com` or `sub2.example.com` are both going to the `sub1` site.

How can I configure this correctly for what I'd like to do. I'm either missing a step or I misunderstand how certificates work. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I can add more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do it -- IIS does not support different certificates on the same port -- only one unique SSL Certificate per IP:port pair (search on this site -- *plenty* of answers for similar questions, for example: [Using several SSL certificates on same IP with IIS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/284807/using-several-ssl-certificates-on-same-ip-with-iis-7) ).

Basically you have 2 choices:

1. Put each site on different HTTPS port: for example 444. You access such site with port number included in URL (which is perfectly fine when used for development or when putting non-important site on SSL) -- `http://sub2.example.com:444/`
2. Generate/Obtain wildcard certificate (`*.example.com`). This site has instructions how then one such certificate can be used by multiple sites: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

Comment: thanks. I thought that I may have to have only one wildcard certificate. SelfSSL7 doesn't appear to generate a wildcard cert though, are there any other (free) tools available that can generate one? I don't want to pay for a cert for dev/staging purposes only.

Comment: I went with the IIS 7.5 `Create Self Signed Certificate` in the end, with a name of `*.example.com`. This works and allows me to set the host name on the HTTPS binding on each site. It would be good if one could also control the `cn` names associated with the generated certificate, but I can live with this. Thanks for your help, very much appreciated :)

Comment: @bertie-bassett I guess that you can mark my answer as accepted then (if it was useful) :)

Comment: @LaztOne - Done!