# Securing using SSL multiple web servers behind a single IP address

Tags: ssl, iis-7, reverse-proxy, windows

### Background

We have number of web servers serving services and pages behind a single IP address we want to use SSL to secure the connection from the clients to those servers.

We access the web servers from the outside using subdomains and a reverse proxy (IIS 7) listening to the traffic and routing accordingly. E.g. **client1.customers.example.com** goes to one webserver and **client2.customers.example.com** goes to another webserver.

### What we need

My question is how to access those resources from the outside using SSL? Do I need to put a wildcard certificate on the reverse proxy itself that is signed on *.customers.example.com? (and what are the down sides of using a wildcard certificate?) or should I use different certificate for each domain? or maybe something compeletly different?

### Additional points:

1. We don't care that the connection within our network (between the reverse proxy and the web servers itself) wouldn't be under SSL.
2. I currently have around 4 subdomains (clients 1 throught 4) this number shouldn't grow dramatically but I do want to have some kind of scalability.
3. I need to have the middle subdomain (**customers**.example.com) cause example.com goes to a different IP (not the one that has reverse proxy listening)

Trying to get this SSL thingy once and for all :)

**EDIT:** There's no other option except for SNI and a "wildcard certificate". I'm now looking for ways to make the reverse-proxy on IIS 7.5 to work with SSL/TLS SNI certificate.

Related questions I've found:

1. [Securing Two Sub domains on IIS7.5 with SSL on port 443](https://serverfault.com/questions/288267/securing-two-sub-domains-on-iis7-5-with-ssl-on-port-443?rq=1)
2. [Multiple SSL domains on the same IP address and same port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/109800/multiple-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip-address-and-same-port)
3. [Using several SSL certificates on same IP with IIS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/284807/using-several-ssl-certificates-on-same-ip-with-iis-7)

**SOLVED** using a wildcard for subdomains under my domain and a ARR extension on my IIS 7.5 server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple SSL domains on the same IP address and same port?](http://serverfault.com/questions/109800/multiple-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip-address-and-same-port)

Comment: @ShaneMadden thanks for the link, I guess that question has most of the answers I needed except for how to work with SNI in IIS enviroment and a reverse proxy

Comment: @UriMay You can't. As I noted in [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/417580/126632) to that question, SNI support on IIS requires IIS 8. Microsoft was _very_ late to the party, again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can I use IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite to and rewrite the url to regular http and with the correct internal address after the reverse proxy terminated the SSL session?

Comment: No. You must have IIS 8 or another server which supports SNI. Again, see the answer I already posted.

Comment: @MichaelHampton commercial software vendors are late to the party whenever marketing believes they would get away with it. No reason to create a superb and innovative product if you could sell a mediocre one for the same amount of money as well - preferably repeatedly.

Comment: @UriMay If your reverse proxy is terminating SSL, then it's the system that would need SNI support.  What software does it run?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I ended up using a wildcard certificate for the subdomains under my domain and an IIS server running ARR and url re-write to make sure the requests gets to the right internal server. Oh and the proxy is terminating the SSL. Thanks everyone for replying.